# What could cause Neovim indent being boken?

Tags: python, vim, indentation, neovim

For clear example I provide asciinema video:
https://asciinema.org/a/vDCTKv09RhxpceISVHlA45ytk

```
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set autoindent
set smartindent
```

It happens because of one of the pluggins.
Thanks @doopNudles

Update1:

```
➜ nvim pwd
/home/kaldown/.config/nvim
➜  nvim tree
.

0 directories, 0 files
```

it works with `--clean`, but does not works when nothing inside directory.
Using `vim-nightly`

Comment: Your screencast shows you're using plugins. Do the same test, but start vim with `vim --clean test.py` and see if the behavior changes. If it does, your plugins or your own config are the problem.

Comment: What exactly is your question about this? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I though this is not the right way to set indentation for python. Turns out some plugins are overriding this config, and that's the reason

Comment: So your question is "why is it like that"?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RyanHainingthanks, moved to https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/29585/what-could-cause-neovim-indent-being-boken

Comment: Looks like you need solution mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562220/vim-indentation-levels-with-parentheses-and-brackets

Comment: @Vijay Thanks, but I believe it can be solved without additional script